# Upgrading RAM. Speed compatibility

Tags: memory, upgrade, speed

I have an older machine. I'm planning to upgrade its RAM memory (DDR2-Synch DRAM PC3200). I mostly find memory speeds of 533, 667 and 800 mhz. Does it have a significant impact if I install cards with higher speeds?

Machine specs:

http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06b/12132708-12132884-12132884-12132884-12133128-12133130-64704643.html?dnr=2

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question: [Can A 800MHz Memory Stick Be Used In A 400MHz Slot](http://superuser.com/questions/8511/can-a-800mhz-memory-stick-be-used-in-a-400mhz-slot)

Comment: If your motherboards BIOS has a way to force a specific memory speed and timings you can get all of them to work correctly using lowest common denominator settings.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the specs from your link, I presume your motherboard can take DDR2 DRAM PC3200 as the maximum speed of your memory sticks. PC3200 is memory at 400Mhz.

If you put a higher clocked memory it will work at 400Mhz. The only difference might be in the [latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency), but for normal people who don't work or game only benchmarks all day, there is no visible difference.

So the answer is no, you won't see any significant impact.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest faster memory many motherboards won't boot with faster memory installed.

Comment: @Ramhound where did you get that idea? [Higher-speed DDR2 DIMMs are compatible with lower-speed DDR2 DIMMs although the motherboard or CPU memory controller will be bound to the limits of the lower-performance modules.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Backward_compatibility) I put DDR2 DIMMs 800Mhz in DDR2 667Mhz compatible PC and it worked, I put mixed 667Mhz and 800Mhz DDR2 SO-DIMMs into 533Mhz compatible laptop and it worked.

Comment: the hundreds of Superuser questions on this subject say otherwise my personal experience and techical knowledge agrees with you ( for the most part) I still like the (it depends) when dealing with memory and motherboards